# Unable to make two views to occupy the screen equally

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am using the following code to create a table layout containing text view and spinner.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Form"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:entries="@array/action"/>

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The problem is that the width of both Text View and spinner are not equal. The size of spinner becomes small when the size of text view is big. How can i sort out this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `width` of both of them to zero instead of the `wrap_content`.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

When you're using `weight` and `width` at the same time, the `width` attribute will override the `weight`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Form"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using weight attribute and total weight.